# Karma/Jasmine tests throwing error when I modify the DOM

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am learning how to unit test with Karma and Jasmine. I have set up some basic tests but as soon as I use some script to modify the DOM in any way the tests error. My script:

```
var testScript = (function() {

  this.example = 'example';

  this.addSomeHtml = function() {
    var header = document.getElementById('header');
    var node = document.createElement('p');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode('This is a paragraph to test.');
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    header.appendChild(node);
  }

  return {
    example: example,
    addSomeHtml: addSomeHtml
  }

})();

testScript.addSomeHtml();
```

My tests:

```
describe('JUST WORK!!!!', function() {

  it('should have a defned var called example', function() {
    expect(testScript.example).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('expect a function called addSomeHtml', function() {

    expect(testScript.addSomeHtml).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The tests do not run when I run the addSomeHtml method and give me an error in my command line of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

As soon as I comment out the call to addSomeHtml the tests are running?